# Like for like analysis in SQL i.e. sum the sales of all stores excluding new and closed stores

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to do [**like for like**](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/likeforlikesales.asp)  `analysis in SQL Server`. For example I would like to `sum up the sales of all the stores with sales>0` throughout the whole period of time (not counting the sales of new stores or closed stores). Is there a simple way for that?

[image]

Only the `sales of store 1 and 3` should be included in the sum, since only those two stores have sales in all three periods. `Store 2` should be excluded because it is `NEW` and it was not running in the first period. `Store 4` should be excluded because it was closed (not running in the `period 3`).

Comment: Can you specify a table structure and columns? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this also. I also add `Max(period)`

```
declare @s table(store int, period int, sales int)

insert into @s values 
(1,1,142),
(1,2,109),
(1,3,126),
(2,2,133),
(2,3,123),
(3,1,114),
(3,2,171),
(3,3,125),
(4,1,199),
(4,2,121)

select store from @s group by store having count(period) > 2

select 
period , MAX(Period), sum(sales)
from @s where 
store in (
select store from @s group by store having count(period) > 2
)
group by period
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should return expected result:

```
select
period,
sum(sales) as Sum
from
(
 select
 period,
 count(*) over (partition by store) as period_count,
 sales from table1
) data
where data.period_count=3
group by period
```

In the condition: "where data.period_count=3", 3 is a desired number of periods that must exist for a store (so it exclude new and closed stores).

Below is code using CTE - handles multiple sales records for given store and period and show store number for period:

```
;with table2 as
(select 
 store, 
 period,
 count(*) over (partition by store) as period_count,
 sum(sale) as sale 
 from table1
 group by store, period)
select
period,
count(store) as StoreNumber,
sum(sale) as Sum
from table2
where 
table2.period_count=(select top 1
count(*) from table2
group by store
order by count(*) desc
)
group by period
```

Comment: Can you please give a suggestion how MAX(Period) should be applied so that the query will work regardless of the number of periods?

Comment: You can change condition `data.period_count = 3` to `data.period_count=(select top 1
count(*) 
from table1
group by store
order by count(*) desc
)`. That should get maximum count from existing records.

Comment: how to count the number of stores in each period? (should be the same number in each period if we do like for like analysis). Note that the count should be done on Store variable within Period (I have a few sales records in for one store in the same period - i.e. store 1 in the period 1 could sell 5 times).

Comment: Note that having counted number of stores may not be sufficient to trust the results. For example if in given period one store closes and another one opens, the store count would'nt change but you will be compare data from different store set.

Comment: If a store opens or closes it will have less period counts than max possible number (other stores will have more periods) so it won't be included in analysis.

Comment: Yep, that is true:) My second query should then be valid.